# To convert m by n matrix to 1 by n matrix

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to convert 127 by 4 matrix to 1 by 4 matrix such that each value in the output row equivalent to average of all values in that particular column.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and which particular part are you having difficulty with ?

Comment: Sir i got 127 bounding boxes with 4 columns. i want to obtain a single bounding box.

Comment: Averaging bounding boxes sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Given the [OP's previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317074/multi-class-svm-for-facial-expression-recognition) it sounds like *merging* the bounding boxes might be a better idea ?

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the `mean` function:

```
A = rand(127,4);
B = mean(A,1);      % Average of A along the first dimension
```

Best,